# Each order receive two records on sales flat order address table on Magento 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento

I need to insert only one record on sales flat order address table for each order, as i need to insert only billing address. i am able to hide shipping address on UI but still received 2 records for each order one for shipping and one for billing.

Comment: what you have done till now?

Answer (score 0):

hide shipping address on UI doesn't help, you need to remove shipping address from quote table.
try this:

```
     $shippingaddress = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()
->getShippingAddress()->unsetData();
```